# Shorting list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to short the list items when i write any word in the input box using jquery or any other language

```
<div class="container">
<form>
   <label id="stylem">Name</label>
   <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
</form>

<div id="design">
  <ul>
       <li>Manish</li>
       <li>Rahul</li>
       <li>Ankit</li>
       <li>Kapil</li>
       <li>Nisha</li>
       <li>Somiya</li>
       <li>Lovely</li>
       <li>Hashim</li>
       <li>Rihana</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: For this case I personally would use jQuery UI's `autocomplete` plugin. Take a look at: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: i want to short form the give list below

Answer (score 1):

You could take a feature of HTML5: [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist):

> The **HTML `<datalist>` element** contains a set of [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) elements that represent the values available for other controls.

```html
<input list="names" name="design" id="design" placeholder="Search">
<datalist id="names">
    <option value="Manish">
    <option value="Rahul">
    <option value="Ankit">
    <option value="Kapil">
    <option value="Nisha">
    <option value="Somiya">
    <option value="Lovely">
    <option value="Hashim">
    <option value="Rihana">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(".search").on("input",function() {
  var $li = $("#design li"), text = $li.text();
  $li.toggle(text.indexOf(this.value)==0); // or != -1 for anywhere in text
});
```